# Question about close or exit apk

Tags: android

How do i close the apk or in other words to EXIT the APK .  i have try finish but it just closing the current activity and i need to close all the activities in the apk??

Comment: Don't do this. It goes against Android UI guidelines and is the first sign to a user that the developer is not interested in writing a well-behaved Android app. See the Reto Meier post linked below.

Answer (score 2):

Applications are just loose confederations of activities, and there's no notion of "exiting an application" built into Android.  If you want to do something that simulates exiting, you'll have to manually keep track of which activities still exist and `finish()` each one in the list.

It's better to design your application without the concept of "exiting" and let the system destroy its parts as needed.  This fits in with one of Android's design principles, which is that the user may want to return to an application he left without the delays of a full-up restart.  If there are things in your activities that need to be wound down, take advantage of the activity lifecycle and do them in the appropriate `onXXX()` method.

Answer (score 0):

This was asked a lot of times but I can't find the link right now. Same answer as I did before:

Short:
You shouldn't.
Read Reto Meier's opinion about the subject: [When to Include an Exit Button in Android Apps (Hint: Never)](http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2010/05/when-to-include-exit-button-in-android.html)

Long:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog = null;

        switch (id) {
        case MENU_QUIT:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.main_screen_quit_text))
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton(
                            getString(R.string.main_screen_quit_yes),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {

                                    moveTaskToBack(true);
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.main_screen_quit_no),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            return alert;
        default:
            dialog = null;
        }
        return dialog;
    }
```